# Symfony2 Get entities of an entity in another entity

Tags: php, symfony

This question is about Symfony2 table relationships using ORM. I have three tables/entities that are related to each other. The relationship is very similar to Wordpress Posts, Categories and Categories relationship tables.

Table 1 contains posts.
Table 2 contains categories
Table 3 contains relationships between the categories and posts.

I want to be able to have the categories property in the posts table and a posts property in the categories table. So that when I call.

Categories->posts : I should get posts in that category.
Posts->categories : I should get the categories the post belongs to.

I want to have unique categories per table and I want all posts to point to a category without having to create a new entry for the category that already exists which is what ManyToOne or OneToMany is offering this is why the third table I think is necessary.

For example here is the relationships

```
class Category_relationship
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="object_id", type="bigint")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Worksheet",         inversedBy="category_relationships")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="worksheet_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $objectId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="bigint")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $categoryId;

}
```

Here is the Category class:

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category_relationship", mappedBy="categoryId", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    protected $posts;
}
```

Here is the Category class:

```
class Posts
{    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category_relationship", mappedBy="objectId", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    protected $categories;
}
```

I want to create a system where I can assign posts to a category but the category table can only contain 1 entry about the category. I also want to be able to use expressions link;

Post->categories
Category->posts

or

Post->AddCategory()
Category->AddPost()

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that many to one relationships do not work for what you need, I think they would work perfectly. Have you tried implementing this?

Comment: And no need for a third table, you can handle this with a foreign key in the owning side (doctrine takes care of all of this)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want multiple entries of the same category created in the category table each time I attach a category to a post. I want there to be one record for a unique category and many posts can be assigned to that category. Posts may have many categories.

Comment: Then use a many to many relationship as suggested in the answer below

Comment: The solution below creates duplicate category entries in the category table. I don't want this. I want each category to be unique in the categories table but able to have many posts some how. I also want the posts table to have a unique post also able to have many categories.

Comment: it does not create multiple entries. Have you tried it? You will have one table with unique posts, identified by id, another table with unique categories identified by id, and a join take with pairs of post id and category id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want a simple many-to-many relationship.

Every post can have multiple categories, and every category have list of related posts. Many to many handles pivot table by itself.

So, in Post entity you have to declare relationship that way:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="PostsCategories",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $categories;
```

Remember about using Doctrine\ORM\Mapping with ORM alias (you don't have to import all subclasses separately):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

After that, you need to create a new ArrayCollection in class constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And add proper methods, like addCategory:

```
public function addCategory(Category $category)
{
    $this->categories[] = $category;

    return $this;
}
```

You can also add them automatically with:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleName:EntityName
```

Same thing in Category entity, but with a little different definiton:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="categories")
 **/
protected $posts;
```

You can find all of these information in [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

Comment: But note. I cannot have a post_id in the categories table as this would mean that each category entry belongs to a particular post [ONLY]. This is not what I want. I want each entry in the category table to be as unique as each entry in the posts table. Thus unique entities that can have many entities of each other without duplicates. This sounds impossible even outside of the doctrine scope without using a third table to record the relationships of the unique entities unless doctrine is able to create an array of posts ids in the posts column or array of category ids in the categories column

Comment: It doesn't create a post_id in categories table.
Many-to-many creates a pivot table between post and category.
And that table will only have two columns: post_id and category_id.
So the foreign keys are in pivot table.

In that case, every post can have multiple categories, and every category can have multiple posts.

If you don't understand something about it, just let us know.

Comment: So if I will be able to use expressions like;

PostEntity->categories

or 

CategoryEntity->posts

...and this will return the categories or the posts respectively?

Comment: More like $post->getCategories() and $category->getPosts(), but yes, it'll return appropriate collections.

Remember to create (or generate) all of needed getters and setters, you can do that simply by calling:

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleName:EntityName